# Final Year Project - Issues with OpenWeatherMap API on Node Red

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, weather, openweathermap

I am currently producing a smart mirror system that uses user behaviour and weather information to produce a recommendation to a user.

I am using Node Red, on a raspberry Pi, with an LCD screen to do so.

However, When trying to use the 'Open Weather Map' Node on node red - The data is read-in through the api. However, no output is being produced.

- Has anyone got any suggestions of other weather data APIs for Node Red?
  OR
- Has anyone had any issues with this API, and understand how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bethany.S - can you provide some specific details of what you have tried? What does your flow look like? Please edit your question with the extra information. It is very hard to help identify the problem you're hitting without any specific details.

Comment: How are you calling this openWeatherMap api?